# using SPFolder as property type in my classes.. is good or bad?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

SPFolder as property type in my classes.. is good or bad?
Example:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass (string sourceWebUrl, string destWebUrl)
        {
            SourceWebUrl = sourceWebUrl;
            DestWebUrl = destWebUrl;
        }

        public string SourceWebUrl { get; set; }
        public string DestWebUrl { get; set; }

        public SPFolder SourceFolder
        {
            get
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SourceWebUrl))
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    return web.Lists["xxx"].RootFolder;
                }
            }
        }

        public SPFolder DestFolder
        {
            get
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(DestWebUrl))
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    return web.Lists["yyy"].RootFolder;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass mc = new MyClass("http://site/source", "http://site/dest");

            //using in mc.SourceFolder & mc.DestFolder in code...
            //if (mc.SourceFolder.Name...)
            //...
            //.....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use this property frequently this solution is not good, because in each time when you invoke this property you creates a new site context, make a call to the DB. This operations is not a quick. Also in each time you can work with different instances of your folder, thus it can cause a different problems.

If you would like to use own class to have access to folder you can implement IDisposable class

```
public class ClassName: IDisposable
{
           private SPSite _site;
           private SPWeb _web;
           private SPFolder _folder;

           public SPFolder Folder
           {
                get
                {
                      return _folder;
                }
           }


           public ClassName(string url)
          {
                      _site = new SPSite(url);
                      _web = _site.OpenWeb();

                      _folder = _web.Lists["yyy"].RootFolder;
          }

          public void Dispose()
         {
                     HttpContext.Current = _temp;
                     if (_web != null) _web.Dispose();
                     if (_site != null) _site.Dispose();
          }
}
```

Its prevent situation when you try to work with folder in other site context.

Comment: And in a lot of cases when you reference a property of the folder/item returned from a Disposed web SharePoint needs the List which needs the Web, so SharePoint will revitalize the disposed web and then leak that revitalized instance. Check your ULS logs to see if that's the case